# How to calculate how many possible combinations/variants?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Lets say I have a car with $7$ different parts. $6$ of those parts each have $10$ different variations $1$ of the parts have $3$ different variants. How many possible combinations can be created between all of the parts combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a very basic combinatorics problem. Try researching a bit since this will definitley provide you with more information on what to learn.

I suppose you are in high school and learning about the topic.

As far as this problem goes, we have 6 parts with 10 different variations. this gives

10×10×10×10×10×10=1,000,000 possibilities.

Now, for each of these possibilites, we have 3 variations of the last part that we could combine it with, giving us a total of

1,000,000×3 = 3,000,000 possibilities.

Comment: I thought this was how it was done. But it's been a while since I've had a math problem like this. Thank you.